# Is it possible to include extra bytes at the end of the data payload when executing a contract method?

Tags: evm

I wanna add extra bytes at the end of the data payload.

For example, in this contract :

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.21;

contract Test {
    constructor() {}

    uint256 public foo;

    function test(uint256 bar) public {
        foo = bar;
    }
}
```

When calling the `test` function with `uint256 bar = 1`

It's calldata is :

`0x29e99f070000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`

But i wanna add the extra data `deadbeaf` like this :

`0x29e99f070000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001deafbeaf`

In my case, this calldata works well, but i don't eusure this extra data's unexpected effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, additional data can be added at the end without affecting the execution results.

Comment: Is there any possibility of unexpected effects in the future?

Comment: No, according to the function Selector, the subsequent bytes of decode will be ignored if there is no corresponding variable.